# Python: Extract random no. of lines from a text file between markers

Tags: python, python-2.7, extract, text-extraction

I have some text files containing 1000+ lines. It contains some lines in the format:

```
seq open @ 2018/02/26 23:07:51 node: \nodes\wroot.nod (wroot)
seq call @ 2018/02/26 23:07:51 node: ttt
retrieve BIOS data using F:\tools64\BiosConfigUtility64.exe /GetConfig:\working\bcudump.txt
BCU is working
seq done @ 2018/02/26 23:07:55 node:ttt

seq call @ 2018/02/26 23:07:55 node: fff
Open the firewall
Firewall opened
seq done @ 2018/02/26 23:07:57 node: fff

seq call @ 2018/02/26 23:07:57 node: \nodes\wchkefierror.bat (wroot#9^wchkefierror)
seq done @ 2018/02/26 23:07:57 node: \nodes\wchkefierror.bat (wroot#9^wchkefierror)

seq call @ 2018/02/26 23:07:57 node: \nodes\wuutmont.bat PTEFIE (wroot#12^wuutmont)

SENDING UUTMonitor.exe /timeevent:PTEFIE
seq done @ 2018/02/26 23:07:58 node: \nodes\wuutmont.bat PTEFIE (wroot#12^wuutmont)

seq call @ 2018/02/26 23:07:58 node: \nodes\wProcessInit.bat (wroot#13^wProcessInit)

02/26/2018 23:07:59 : @@@@ begin_\process\ProcessInit.bat

<BISCON Version=xxxx">
x
y
</BISCON>
\process\ProcessInit.bat:::Parsing branding variables from INI files...
found \flags\custom.ini
PRODUCTIONLOCK not defined in custom.ini
\process\ProcessInit.bat:::Calling SETVAR.BAT generated from INI data...
02/26/2018 23:08:04 : @@@@ end\process\ProcessInit.bat
seq done @ 2018/02/26 23:08:04 node: \nodes\wProcessInit.bat (wroot#13^wProcessInit)

seq log @ 2018/02/26 23:08:04 node: skipping wroot#14^wbios as \flags\bios_flash_wnd.trg file not exists

seq call @ 2018/02/26 23:08:04 node: aaa

Get SkeletonPO from \working\ubera.ini
seq done @ 2018/02/26 23:08:04 node: aaa
```

I want to extract the lines between seq call and seq done in a list and insert NULL in the list if the line starts with seq open or seq log.

As you can see there may be any random no. of lines even 0 between seq call and seq done. I have been trying to find answers but to no avail. Also I am new in python.

Expected output for the above sample:

```
NULL
retrieve BIOS data using F:\tools64\BiosConfigUtility64.exe /GetConfig:\working\bcudump.txt
BCU is working
Open the firewall
Firewall opened
NULL
SENDING UUTMonitor.exe /timeevent:PTEFIE
02/26/2018 23:07:59 : @@@@ begin_\process\ProcessInit.bat

<BISCON Version=xxxx">
x
y
</BISCON>
\process\ProcessInit.bat:::Parsing branding variables from INI files...
found \flags\custom.ini
PRODUCTIONLOCK not defined in custom.ini
\process\ProcessInit.bat:::Calling SETVAR.BAT generated from INI data...
02/26/2018 23:08:04 : @@@@ end\process\ProcessInit.bat
NULL
Get SkeletonPO from \working\ubera.ini
```

Comment: Why is there a second `NULL` in the  expected output? According to the input and the conditions given by you `NULL`  only comes when you have seq open or seq log. But there seems to be none for second `NULL`

Comment: the second NULL is for:
`seq call @ 2018/02/26 23:07:57 node: \nodes\wchkefierror.bat (wroot#9^wchkefierror)
seq done @ 2018/02/26 23:07:57 node: \nodes\wchkefierror.bat (wroot#9^wchkefierror)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick and dirty approach to get what you want:

```
def extractTxt(fpth, joinchar=' '):
    loglines = []
    with open(fpth) as f:
        incall = False
        calllines = []

        for line in f:
            if line.startswith('seq open') or line.startswith('seq log'):
                loglines.append('NULL')
            elif line.startswith('seq call'):
                incall = True
            elif incall:
                if line.startswith('seq done'):
                    incall = False
                    call = joinchar.join(l for l in calllines if l)
                    calllines = []

                    if not call.strip():
                        loglines.append('NULL')
                    else:
                        loglines.append(call)
                else:
                    calllines.append(line.strip())

    return loglines

extractTxt('seq.txt')
```

Output:

```
['NULL',
 'retrieve BIOS data using F:\\tools64\\BiosConfigUtility64.exe /GetConfig:\\working\\bcudump.txt BCU is working',
 'Open the firewall Firewall opened',
 'NULL',
 'SENDING UUTMonitor.exe /timeevent:PTEFIE',
 '02/26/2018 23:07:59 : @@@@ begin_\\process\\ProcessInit.bat <BISCON Version=xxxx"> x y </BISCON> \\process\\ProcessInit.bat:::Parsing branding variables from INI files... found \\flags\\custom.ini PRODUCTIONLOCK not defined in custom.ini \\process\\ProcessInit.bat:::Calling SETVAR.BAT generated from INI data... 02/26/2018 23:08:04 : @@@@ end\\process\\ProcessInit.bat',
 'NULL',
 'Get SkeletonPO from \\working\\ubera.ini']
```

You can change how the separate lines in each call are joined together in the list entries by passing a different `joinchar` parameter to `extractTxt`. I'll leave any further styling/organization tasks as exercises.

## details

The line:

```
call = joinchar.join(l for l in calllines if l)
```

does a couple of different things. The [`join` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) will join a list of strings together using the string that precedes it. For example, the following expression:

```
', '.join(['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'bof'])
```

will produce this output:

```
'foo, bar, baz, bof'
```

The part of the line inside the parenthesis:

```
l for l in calllines if l
```

is something called a [generator expression](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/python-list-comprehensions-vs-generator-expressions-cef70ccb49db). This is a bit more complicated to explain, but basically all it's doing here is making a "list" of all the lines in `calllines` that are not empty. See the linked page for more details if you're curious. You can simplify the line somewhat by expanding it. All together, the following lines:

```
call = ''
for l in calllines:
    # l evaluates to False if it is empty
    if l:
        call += l + joinchar

# remove any trailing joinchar
if call.endswith(joinchar):
    call = call[:-len(joinchar)]
```

will have the same effect as the single line `call = joinchar.join(l for l in calllines if l)`.

Comment: Yes. Sorry. Corrected it.

Comment: @ImdadulChoudhury I updated the code. The output now exactly matches your sample. If you have any questions about how it works, feel free to ask

Comment: This works but as I mentioned I want to append it in a list. So when I append it to a list all the lines are treated individually. For eg.-
`Open the firewall
Firewall opened` 
needs to come in a single line

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Does my work with. But can you please tell me about this line `call = joinchar.join(l for l in calllines if l)`.

Comment: @ImdadulChoudhury I added some relevant details/explanation

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

begins_with_open_or_log=re.compile(r'seq open|seq log')
begins_with_call_and_done=re.compile(r'seq call|seq done')

with open('log.txt') as f:
    lines=f.readlines()
i=0
for line in lines:
    if re.match(begins_with_open_or_log,line):
        lines[i]='NULL\n'
    elif re.match(begins_with_call_and_done,line):
        lines[i]=''
    elif line=='\n':
        lines[i]=''
    i+=1
print (''.join(lines),end='')
```

> I want to extract the lines between seq call and seq done in a list and insert NULL in the list if the line starts with seq open or seq log.

this is, probably, your desired output:

```
NULL
retrieve BIOS data using F:\tools64\BiosConfigUtility64.exe /GetConfig:\working\bcudump.txt
BCU is working
Open the firewall
Firewall opened
SENDING UUTMonitor.exe /timeevent:PTEFIE
02/26/2018 23:07:59 : @@@@ begin_\process\ProcessInit.bat
<BISCON Version=xxxx">
x
y
</BISCON>
\process\ProcessInit.bat:::Parsing branding variables from INI files...
found \flags\custom.ini
PRODUCTIONLOCK not defined in custom.ini
\process\ProcessInit.bat:::Calling SETVAR.BAT generated from INI data...
02/26/2018 23:08:04 : @@@@ end\process\ProcessInit.bat
NULL
Get SkeletonPO from \working\ubera.ini
```

but, if your are serious about this:

> I want to extract the lines between seq call and seq done

note that, for example, the line

```
retrieve BIOS data using F:\tools64\BiosConfigUtility64.exe /GetConfig:\working\bcudump.txt
```

doesn't belongs to your output... you need to be as precise as possible

---

Note: for python 2.7, change this line

```
print (''.join(lines),end='')
```

for this one:

```
print ''.join(lines)
```

Comment: Since `retrieve BIOS data using F:\tools64\BiosConfigUtility64.exe` 
is between
`seq call @ 2018/02/26 23:07:51 node: ttt
retrieve BIOS data using F:\tools64\BiosConfigUtility64.exe /GetConfig:\working\bcudump.txt
BCU is working
seq done @ 2018/02/26 23:07:55 node:ttt`
So it needs to be in the outout.